# How to read audio stream that our system (PC soundcard or speakers) is playing in java

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, soundcard

I am trying to play audio stream which is read from audio playing in another system.

Could please tell me the how to read the audio bytes that our PC is playing audio currently.

Thanks & Regards
Yamini.

Comment: Take a look at [Java Sound API](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info)

Comment: This is not possible without an audio loopback driver or a sound device that supports it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked many times. The answer is that the feature you want is not supported by Java (in fact, it is hard todo in any environment). This is not unreasonable since some operating systems don't support it. Your options are:

- use a cable to connect the PCs output to its input. If you use an analog cable this will introduce some noise.
- Use software like soundflower (mac only) to create a virtual cable.
- Use JNI to access a low-level API for your system that can do it.